# Gauss-Bonnet correction to Carnot's efficiency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, black-holes, gauss-bonnet

Could anyone tell explicitly, how did the author get the $T_c$  vs.  $\alpha$ plot given in Figure 3 in [Gauss-Bonnet Black Holes and Holographic Heat Engines Beyond Large N](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08782v2).

Comment: the software used to compute the iteration is not included ...

Comment: We proceed with analytic expressions insteed numerical values, we can solve the equation of state using perturbation methods,  but my question is, how to get $Tc$  VS  $\alpha$ plot

Comment: it seems that it is completly detailled until the iteration in 22 with the last values. Sorry I can't help but I'm interested ... You need an expert